# How do I perform an operation after completion of the action to be performed after the observable is complete?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I need to perform an action on the result of an observable within an observable.

**`Component`**

```
checkIn(room: Room)
{
    this.roomService.checkIn(room.number).subscribe(
        response => {
           this.checkInResponse = response;
           // other codes

           this.getRooms();

           // Perform the following line of code after getRooms() is complete, i.e. this.rooms has been reloaded. Right now, it executes instantaneously, i.e. before this.getRooms() is complete.
           this.setRoom = this.roomFromNumber(room.number);
        },
        error => {
           console.log(error);
        }
    );
 }

getRooms() {
    this.roomService.getRooms().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.rooms = response;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
}
```

**`Service`**

```
getRooms(): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/rooms?token=' + this.token).map(
        (response: Response) => {
            return response.json().rooms;
        });
 }

checkIn(roomNumber: number) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/room/checkIn?token=' + this.token,
    {
        number: roomNumber
    },
    {
      headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
      })
    });
}
```

The problem in the code above is that the `this.setRoom = this.roomFromNumber(room.number);` executes before `this.getRooms()`. I need to perform the following line of code after getRooms() is complete, i.e. this.rooms has been reloaded.

I could simply do the following which waits for two seconds before executing the code, which work fine if the observable happens within two seconds; which most definitely isn't the correct approach.

```
setTimeout(() => this.setRoom = this.roomFromNumber(room.number), 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
checkIn(room: Room)
{
    this.roomService.checkIn(room.number).subscribe(
        response => {
           this.checkInResponse = response;
           // other codes

           this.getRooms(() => { this.setRoom = this.roomFromNumber(room.number); });.

        },
        error => {
           console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

getRooms(completeAction: any) {
    this.roomService.getRooms().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.rooms = response;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => { completeAction(); }
    );
}
```

Comment: I made it work another way. I'll try this one and let you know if it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkIn(room: Room)
{
    this.roomService.checkIn(room.number).subscribe(
        (response) => {
           this.checkInResponse = response;
           // other codes

           this.getRooms().subscribe(
           (data) => {
               // executes after getRooms() has completed execution
               this.setRoom = this.roomFromNumber(room.number);
           },
           (error) => {
               console.log(error);
           });
        },
        (error) => {
           console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

getRooms() {
    return this.roomService.getRooms().map(
           (response) => {
                return response
            }
           ).catch((error) => {
               return Observable.throw(error)
          });
}
```